How to create evil-snipe like transient state? Use all keys as usual, except the custom ones repeating the last command
I am using doom emacs on Mac OS. I want to know how I could create a function with transient state functionality like in evil-snipe mode.
For example, let's say I want to have a repeated zap-up-to-char function, such that I zap to char and if I press some defined key in this custom function I zap further to the next same char.
I was thinking to define the function by going into visual mode, use evil-snipe and then delete. The problem, is that I quit the evil-snipe state and even if I wouldn't I would want not to just jump to the next same char, but to execute the whole routine - going into visual mode, use evil-snipe and then delete.
evil-repeat which should do exactly this doesn't work for a lot of functions unfortunately.
Does someone know how I could get the aforementioned function and have a transient state behaving like usual except for some special keys?
